# Show that $|x^\ast Ay|=|x^\ast By|$ iff. $A=e^{i\theta}B$.

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

Let $A,B\in M_n$. Show that $|x^\ast Ay|=|x^\ast By|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ iff $A=e^{i\theta}B$ for some $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$.

The one side is easy to prove by plugging $e^{i\theta}B$ in and taking out $e^{i\theta}$, and $|e^{i\theta}|=1$. For the other side, I know that I may use Toeplitz decomposition to write $|x^\ast Ay|=|\frac{1}{2}x^\ast (A+A^\ast)y+i\frac{1}{2i}x^\ast(A-A^\ast)y|$, I might need to check $A+A^\ast=\sin\theta B$ and $\frac{1}{2i}(A-A^\ast)=B$, but I'm stuck here. Plus, I might also write $|x^\ast Ay|$ to $|\sum_{i,j=0}^na_{i,j}\bar{x_i}y_j|$ and $|x^\ast By|$ to |$\sum_{i,j=0}^nb_{i,j}\bar{x_i}y_j|$, but I have no ideas how to prove in this way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strategy talk: the condition is that the norms must be equal for *all* $x, y$. This is *extremely strong.* So, it may be a good idea to proceed by contraposition, presuming the elements of the matrices don't satisfy our target statement somewhere, and try to construct a pathological case that demonstrates the antecedent's failure.
In fact, while trying to do such a proof, you might find one that reads easier directly, with your pathological $x,y$ supposed from the beginning; that's what happened to me here.

If $|x^*Ay| = |x^*By|$ in general, then it must also hold for the particular vectors $x = a_{ij}\hat{e}_i$ and $y = a_{ij}\hat{e}_j$ for each $0 \leq i,j \leq n$ (chosen to "pick out" the ${ij}$ term of the matrix).
This yields $x^*Ay = a_{ij}^*a_{ij}^2 = |a_{ij}|a_{ij}$.
The norm of this is, using multiplicativity,  $|a_{ij}|^2$.
One also has $x^*By = a_{ij}^*b_{ij}a_{ij} = |a_{ij}|b_{ij}$, whose norm is $|a_{ij}||b_{ij}|$; equating these,
$$|a_{ij}|^2 = |a_{ij}||b_{ij}| \Leftrightarrow |a_{ij}| = |b_{ij}|$$
(In the case $a_{ij} = 0$ it can be shown $b_{ij} = 0$ by taking $x = \hat{e}_i$ and $y = \hat{e}_j$)

Complex numbers whose norm is identical only differ by a phase.
Can you see how to use this kind of argument to show that it must be the *same* phase for any two matrix elements?

P.S. My initial attempts to finish this were frustrated, but I've got other things to attend to and I don't want to give the whole answer in case this is a homework problem; try working with a linear combination, since you'll need interactions between two terms. The triangle inequalities may also be good to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'll try by myself then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ and $v$ be two fixed vectors. If $|\langle x,u\rangle|=|\langle x,v\rangle|$ for every vector $x$, then by putting $x=u$ and $x=v$, we see that $\|u\|^2=|\langle u,v\rangle|=\|v\|^2$. It follows that $\|u\|=\|v\|$ and $|\langle u,v\rangle|=\|u\|\|v\|$. The latter equality is the case where equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hence one of $u$ or $v$ is a scalar multiple of the other. As $\|u\|=\|v\|$, we must have $v=\omega u$ for some complex number $\omega$ lying on the unit circle.

Thus the given assumption in your question implies that for every vector $y$, $Ay=\omega By$ for some unimodular complex number $\omega$ (that may depend on $y$). In particular, if we take $y$ as a vector in the standard basis, we see that for each $j$, the $j$-th column of $A$ is $\omega_j$ times the $j$-column of $B$ for some $|\omega_j|=1$. Hence $A=B\operatorname{diag}(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)$. Now let
$$
S=\left\{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}:\text{the $j$-th element of } B^\ast x\text{ is nonzero for some }x\in\mathbb C^n\right\}.
$$
By permuting the rows and columns of $A$ and $B$ using the same permutation if necessary, we may assume that $S=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ for some $k\le n$. It follows that for every $x\in\mathbb C^n$, the last $n-k$ elements of $B^\ast x$ are necessarily zero. In particular, the last $n-k$ rows of $B^\ast$ are zero, i.e., the last $n-k$ columns of $B$ are zero.

Now, for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, pick a $y_j=B^\ast x_j$ such that its $j$-th element is nonzero. Then for some linear combination $x=\sum_{j=1}^kc_jx_j$, the first $k$ elements of $y=B^\ast x$ are nonzero and the last $n-k$ elements are zero. Hence
$$
\left|\sum_{j=1}^k\omega_j |y_j|^2\right|
=|y^\ast \operatorname{diag}(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)\,y|=|x^\ast Ay|=|x^\ast By|=|y^\ast y|=\sum_{j=1}^k|y_j|^2.
$$
Therefore $\omega_1=\cdots=\omega_k=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb R$, and $A=B\operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta},\ldots,e^{i\theta},\omega_{k+1},\ldots,\omega_n)$. Since the last $n-k$ columns of $B$ are zero, this means $A=e^{i\theta} B$.